# Simple Timer to Start Counting Up as Page Opens [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, timer, navigation, state, init

I have a page where I want to show users the elapsed time that they are on the page similar to the one Forest app is doing for its pomodoro method. However instead of counting down, mine's counting up.

I've been unable to get the timer to start the moment the page loads. Also I want to make the timer stop and print the elapsed time once user exits the page. And pass the elapsed time data to backend or another page. The package used is https://pub.dev/packages/simple_timer

How would this be best achieved? Thank you experts!

```
class TimerPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _TimerPageState createState() => _TimerPageState();
}

class _TimerPageState extends State<TimerPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TimerController _timerController;
  TimerProgressTextCountDirection _progressTextCountDirection =
      TimerProgressTextCountDirection.count_up;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timerController = TimerController(this);
    _timerController.start();
    _timerController.forward(from: 0.0);
    _timerController.addListener(_printLatestValue);

    super.initState();
  }

  _printLatestValue() {
    print("${_timerController.duration}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff04072E),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Aloha', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: WillPopScope(child: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              child: SimpleTimer(
                controller: _timerController,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
                displayProgressIndicator: false,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                progressTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 60),
              ),
            ),
ElevatedButton( onPressed: ()  {
_printLatestValue();
                Navigator.pushReplacement<void, void>(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>  MainPage()));
              },child: Text('Next'))
          ]),
        ),
      ),
),
    ); 
  }
}
```

The error that appeared after inserting in

```
_timerController.start();
    _timerController.forward(from: 0.0);
```

[image: error after code]

Answer (score 1):

You should call `_timerController.start()` inside `initState` to start the timer :) To show the time or pass it after the user exits the page, you can use two things to do that efficiently: the Navigator pop result and a `WillPopScope` widget. Just wrap the page into a `WillPopScope` and call `Navigator.pop` with a result inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nico. (Updated Code) After I added _timerController.start(), an error saying AnimationController cannot have a duration of null. So I added _timerController.forward(from:0.0). Not sure if that's correct.

I'm looking at the WillPopScope, so the 'Next' button will save the data (elapsed time) and navigate to the next page right?

Another qtn, how do I add a listener to this timer running, so as to print the listened data when the 'Next' button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

In your error screen say...
add this line on initState() before start

```
 _timeController = TimerController.seconds(15);
```